# Iphone application works fine on simulator but crashes on actual devise

Tags: ios, iphone, crash, crash-reports, sigabrt

My application works perfectly on simulator and it doesn't show any warning or error in console but when I test my application on actual device it crashes when I start the application. I have local notification service enabled. I am storing large image file from server into my local database when first view loads. But I tried to launch application without storing images also,still not working.

Following is the crash report I am getting.
Let me know if anyone knows about it.
Thanks in advance.

```
Incident Identifier: B92EC717-8391-4F9A-8C34-3CF9AA2E697C

CrashReporter Key:   e06a9cfad6f483253b1278ac34a2f38ab1b5cd18

Hardware Model:      iPhone7,2

Process:             TimeStamp [268]

Path:                /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/E87AEE22-E2D8-407F-BDA4-EA626D287C98/TimeStamp.app/TimeStamp

Identifier:          SG.TimeStamp

Version:             1 (1.0)

Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)

Parent Process:      launchd [1]

Date/Time:           2015-10-02 10:44:13.13 +0530
Launch Time:         2015-10-02 10:44:13.13 +0530
OS Version:          iOS 9.0.2 (13A452)
Report Version:      105

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Triggered by Thread:  0

Filtered syslog:
None found

Last Exception Backtrace:

0   CoreFoundation                  0x185544f5c 0x185420000 + 1199964

1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x19a13bf80 0x19a134000 + 32640

2   CoreFoundation                  0x185544ea4 0x185420000 + 1199780

3   Foundation                      0x1863b6a0c 0x186390000 + 158220

4   TimeStamp                       0x100049890 -[AppDelegate CopyAndPaste] (AppDelegate.m:104)

5   TimeStamp                       0x100048f2c -[AppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] (AppDelegate.m:21)

6   UIKit                           0x18ab0f184 0x18aa88000 + 553348

7   UIKit                           0x18ad37e60 0x18aa88000 + 2817632

8   UIKit                           0x18ad3c1a4 0x18aa88000 + 2834852

9   UIKit                           0x18ad392e4 0x18aa88000 + 2822884

10  FrontBoardServices              0x18f28b7ec 0x18f264000 + 161772

11  FrontBoardServices              0x18f28bb6c 0x18f264000 + 162668

12  CoreFoundation                  0x1854fc5a4 0x185420000 + 902564

13  CoreFoundation                  0x1854fc038 0x185420000 + 901176

14  CoreFoundation                  0x1854f9d38 0x185420000 + 892216

15  CoreFoundation                  0x185428dc0 0x185420000 + 36288

16  UIKit                           0x18ab080ac 0x18aa88000 + 524460

17  UIKit                           0x18ab02f44 0x18aa88000 + 503620

18  TimeStamp                       0x100050220 main (main.m:14)

19  libdyld.dylib                   0x19a9668b8 0x19a964000 + 10424

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:

0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000019aa831e0 0x19aa68000 + 111072

1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019ab4cf0c 0x19ab48000 + 20236

2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x000000019a9f6b78 0x19a994000 + 404344

3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001997b93f4 0x1997b8000 + 5108

4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001997d5e98 0x1997b8000 + 122520

5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x000000019a13c248 0x19a134000 + 33352

6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001997d2f44 0x1997b8000 + 110404

7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001997d2b10 0x1997b8000 + 109328

8   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x000000019a13c120 0x19a134000 + 33056

9   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000185428e68 0x185420000 + 36456

10  UIKit                           0x000000018ab080ac 0x18aa88000 + 524460

11  UIKit                           0x000000018ab02f44 0x18aa88000 + 503620

12  TimeStamp                       0x0000000100050220 main (main.m:14)

13  libdyld.dylib                   0x000000019a9668b8 0x19a964000 + 10424

Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager

Thread 1:

0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000019aa8459c 0x19aa68000 + 116124

1   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000019a948a04 0x19a934000 + 84484

2   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000019a93793c 0x19a934000 + 14652


Thread 2 name:  Dispatch queue: AXBinaryMonitorQueue

Thread 2:

0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000019aa68c6c 0x19aa68000 + 3180

1   libsystem_platform.dylib        0x000000019ab4297c 0x19ab40000 + 10620

2   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000019a940614 0x19a934000 + 50708

3   AccessibilityUtilities          0x000000018bfe6648 0x18bfc0000 + 157256

4   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000019a9357b0 0x19a934000 + 6064

5   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000019a935770 0x19a934000 + 6000

6   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000019a94175c 0x19a934000 + 55132

7   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000019a939274 0x19a934000 + 21108

8   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000019a935770 0x19a934000 + 6000

9   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000019a943bb0 0x19a934000 + 64432

10  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000019a94334c 0x19a934000 + 62284

11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019ab49478 0x19ab48000 + 5240

12  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019ab49028 0x19ab48000 + 4136

Thread 3:

0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000019aa83c0c 0x19aa68000 + 113676

1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019ab49538 0x19ab48000 + 5432

2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019ab49028 0x19ab48000 + 4136

Thread 4:

0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000019aa83c0c 0x19aa68000 + 113676

1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019ab49538 0x19ab48000 + 5432

2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019ab49028 0x19ab48000 + 4136

Thread 5:

0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000019aa83c0c 0x19aa68000 + 113676

1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019ab49538 0x19ab48000 + 5432

2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019ab49028 0x19ab48000 + 4136

Thread 6:

0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000019aa83c0c 0x19aa68000 + 113676

1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019ab49538 0x19ab48000 + 5432

2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019ab49028 0x19ab48000 + 4136

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x0000000000000000   x1: 0x0000000000000000   x2: 0x0000000000000000   x3: 0x0000000147666967
    x4: 0x00000001997d6e02   x5: 0x000000016fdd3530   x6: 0x000000000000006e   x7: 0x0000000000000f80
    x8: 0x0000000008000000   x9: 0x0000000004000000  x10: 0x0000000000000002  x11: 0x0000000000000010
   x12: 0x0000000000000000  x13: 0x0000000000000002  x14: 0x0000000000000000  x15: 0x0000030000000300
   x16: 0x0000000000000148  x17: 0x0000000000000000  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x0000000000000006
   x20: 0x00000001a13ee000  x21: 0x000000016fdd3530  x22: 0x0000000147619a60  x23: 0x00000001a13f9b68
   x24: 0x0000000000000001  x25: 0xcf00ec12820beef7  x26: 0x0000000147608640  x27: 0x0000000000000000
   x28: 0x0000000000000001  fp: 0x000000016fdd3490   lr: 0x000000019ab4cf0c
    sp: 0x000000016fdd3470   pc: 0x000000019aa831e0 cpsr: 0x00000000

Binary Images -> 
Then there is lot of data that I think might not be of any use.


-(void)CopyAndPaste


{   

 NSArray *arrpath=NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

    NSString *str=[arrpath objectAtIndex:0];

    self.strdbpath=[str stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"time.db"];

    NSLog(@"%@",self.strdbpath);

    if(![[NSFileManager defaultManager]fileExistsAtPath:self.strdbpath])
{
        NSString *localdb=[[NSString alloc]initWithString:[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"time" ofType:@"db"]];

        [[NSFileManager defaultManager]copyItemAtPath:localdb toPath:self.strdbpath error:nil];
    }
}
```

Comment: please edit your question to show the source code of what you are doing in your AppDelegate's "`CopyAndPaste`" function.

Comment: @Paulw11 its somewhere in copeandpaste method.

Comment: well yeah, type command-L and enter 104

Comment: Its one of these two lines. I might have done changes after getting the crash report.
(1) self.strdbpath=[str stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"time.db"];

(2) [[NSFileManager defaultManager]copyItemAtPath:localdb toPath:self.strdbpath error:nil];

Comment: Set a breakpoint in that method and single-step to see where the crash is.  It looks like something is failing there

Comment: Application doesn't crash on simulator. It runs perfectly.
Problem is with when it is opened with  iphone 6.

Comment: That's OK.  You can single-step through the app while running it on an attached iPhone

Comment: Okay.
Let me check it and I will get back to you ASAP.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to store large image file from server during application launch. Based on your code, you're trying to do it **synchronously on main thread**. If you block the main thread for any significant amount of time, the user interface becomes unacceptably unresponsive. In order to keep the user interface responsive, iOS includes a watchdog mechanism. If your application fails to respond to certain user interface events (launch, suspend, resume, terminate) in time, the watchdog will kill your application. To resolve the issue I'd call CopyAndPaste asynchronously:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^(void){
        CopyAndPaste();
    });
```